# Figures detection in a picture using ML.NET

Tags: visual-studio, image-recognition, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

How can I use ML.NET services to detect different figures inside a picture? For example, detecting squares, circles, triangles, etc. At the end of the process, I should receive a solution like:

Number of items detected:
Squares: 5
Circles 7
Triangles: 3
etc...

Is that possible with ML.NET?
Which algorithm should I use?

Thanks for any help.